# How to use Scanner to scan new Line in java?

Tags: java

```
74874 56874
45484  45645
56564  56565
```

The data above are from the File called dataFile

I dunno how to scan line #2 , my program only scan the first line 74874 56874.
i am using the `nextInt()` method.

```
int data1 = dataFile.nextInt();
int data2 = dataFile.nextInt();
anyNewArrival = (((data1%100)+1)<= chancesOfArrival);
transactionTime = (data2%maxTransactionTime)+1;
```

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: is it a file? is it user input? show us some code, then we can guide you

Comment: Just call your code in a loop in order to process the remaining lines.

Comment: that is exactly what loops are for

Comment: Lol we're commenting on a 9-year-old question! 

Answer (score 1):

Use scanner's `hasNextLine()` to check for the existence next line and `nextLine()` to actually obtain it

Check out [this](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/nextline-method-example/) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static String read(String filePath) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(filePath).toFile());
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            result.append(scanner.nextLine());
            result.append("\n");
        }
        scanner.close();
        return result.toString();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```